# Is the optimal transport of radially symmetric measures also radially symmetric?

Tags: measure-theory, optimal-transportation

Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be radially symmetric probability measures on $\mathbb R^d$. Consider the Kantorovich optimal transport problem between $\mu$ and $\nu$, with convex, nonnegative cost. Suppose there exists at least an optimal transport plan between $\mu$ and $\nu$ with finite cost.

> **Question.** Does it follow that any optimal transport plan $\gamma \in \mathcal P (\mathbb R^d \times \mathbb R^d)$ is radially
> symmetric, in the sense that $\gamma$ is concentrated on the set
> $$\{(x, \, y) \mid \ x, \, y \in \mathbb R^d, \ x/|x| = y/|y| \}?$$

Comment: A symmetric optimal plan always exists; it can be obtained by symmetrizing a given optimal plan. Now, I do not know the definition of radial symmetry --- if you assume that central symmetry is radial, then the answer is "no"; it is easy to construct an example with few atoms.

Comment: If radial symmetry is defined by all rotations, then answer is "yes". It follows since the quotient map $\mathbb{R}^d\to [0,\infty)$ is short.

Comment: Yes I do mean invariant under all rotations, sorry. What is a short map? And how does it follow from this?

Comment: Short means distance-nonexpanding. The optimal plan on $[0,\infty)$ lifts uniquely to an optimal plan on $\mathbb{R}^d$

Comment: Is "any=some" or "any=every"? As a non-native English speaker, some usage of "any" always confuses me.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi "any=every"

Comment: Intuitively I would expect this to be false for arbitrary convex, non-negative costs. For instance, what I believe may be a counterexample is a problem with a "shifted" distance cost with center $(x, -x)$, i.e., $c(x, -x) = 0$ for some $x\neq 0$. Maybe the cost function requires some symmetry as well.

Comment: The cost function should of course be radially symmetric as well, indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is my commnent (which nobody sees).*

The answer is "yes".
It follows since the quotient map $\mathbb{R}^d\to[0,\infty)$ is a submetry.
The optimal plan between pushforward measures on $[0,\infty)$ lifts uniquely to an optimal plan on $\mathbb{R}^d$

Comment: (I use that the cost function is a strictly increasing function of distance.)

Comment: I see your comment sir.